# My roblox launcher not starting

Tags: windows

I tried updating my graphic driver and some windows updates and still, it doesn't work. I can't explain the problem clearly here, so I will link a video that has the same problem as mine. I hope anyone can help, thanks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYQ2pcUQr-g&ab_channel=EvConstant

Comment: The game is launching but it's immediantly crashing.

Comment: Can you check logs, EventViewer and share that information here?